# toDataURL() not a function

Tags: javascript, canvas

iFrame code:

```html
<iframe src="http://easyweb.site/embed.php?v=54f85644&amp;statTrack=&amp;w=512&amp;h=288&amp;iframe=1&amp;trimmingType=thumb"
        width="512" height="288" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
        id="set_video_image_popup_iframe">
    #document
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <div class="videobox">
                <video id="media-video"></video>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas" crossorigin="Anonymous" style="width: 538px; height: 288px;"></canvas>
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

JS function:

```js
var getThumbData = function() {
    var b = document.createElement('a');
    b.href = $('#set_video_image_popup_iframe').attr('src');

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = document.referrer;
    var imageData = 'hello';
    if (a.pathname == '/member/video.php' && window.location.pathname == '/embed.php') {

        var video = document.getElementById('media-video');
        var videoCurrentTime = document.getElementById('media-video').currentTime;
        var canvasWidth = $('video').width();
        var canvasHeight = $('video').height();
        var c = $('body').append($('<canvas>', {
            id: 'myCanvas',
            width: canvasWidth,
            height: canvasHeight,
            crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'
        }));
        $('body').append('<button id="btn"></button>');

        var ctx;

        c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        alert('in here');
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

        alert('1');
        alert(c);

        imageData = c.toDataURL();
        console.log(imageData);
        alert('2');
        window.open(imageData, "toDataURL() image", "width=600, height=200");
        return imageData;
    }
}
```

in the above code function returns control to the caller before c.toDataURL() and doesn't print image data in console.
when I try to execute c.toDataURL() in console. it gives a error "Uncaught TypeError: c.toDataURL is not a function(…)".

My js file is called in an iframe

In the js file I create video tag and use the above canvas to get it's data.
How to correct this code?

Comment: can you log and see value of document.getElementById('myCanvas'); could be the case where this executes before canvas loads in dom

Comment: any reason you are overriding `c` two times after you initialized it?

Comment: No reason to override c. just to make sure I get the c before using toDataURL(). However, even after removing the second line it doesn't work.

Comment: I tested your code with a simple `<video>` element, and it works. Please show us the context (Minimal amount of code, but still enough for us to reproduce the issue - HTML code, where this JS code is declared, etc.). @VinodLouis I don't believe that is the problem, since the canvas is created by this snippet itself.

Comment: I can see the canvas loaded and image was drawn on it. but I am not able to use toDataURL() with it.

Comment: <div id="CaptureImagePopup" class="trim_video_outr">

                    <!--<? echo str_replace('v=' . $v->code, 'v=' . $v->code . '&trimmingType=thumb', $v->GetEmbedCode("512", "288", "1", "N", "VideoTrimmer.swf")); ?>-->
                    <iframe src="<?php echo $SITE;?>embed.php?v=<?php echo $v->code;?>&statTrack=&w=512&h=288&iframe=1&trimmingType=thumb" width="512" height="288" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="set_video_image_popup_iframe"></iframe>

                </div> @blex this is the iframe in which my js code is called. The canvas and video tag is in iframe.

Comment: @arun Don't take it badly, but it's like asking "What's wrong with my car? Here is my garage" :) Please add to your question the code which is inside the iframe (not everything, just enough for us to reproduce the problem). And since it is not relevant here, please don't post PHP, but the code that actually appears in the browser (Right click/View source). I hope we'll be able to help you that way. This is the kind of code sample we need to be able to help you (this one works) : https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/9ETJk7sX

Comment: @blex I am sorry I cannot disclose whole code. I hope the code given above will help in solving the problem.

Comment: what does "Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.(…)" means? and how to solve it ?

Comment: @arun In your case, I'm guessing you get this error because your page is not accessed through HTTP(s) (are you accessing it through `file:\\\C:\Users\...`?)

Comment: @blex No I am using virtual host configured to access it. i think the problem is with tainted canvas. I am capturing image from video which is downloaded from s3 bucket. How can I solve it now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several issues here:

- The `canvas` interface [does not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) the `crossorigin` attribute.
  You should really be allowing CORS on an intermediate `img` element to store captured images from the canvas.
- Accessing a canvas embedded in an iframe from a different document may not work, if they're not on the same domain.
  i.e. `c = document.getElementById('myCanvas')` will return an empty result, as this element is not found on the current document (which is not the expected one). Bypass this using the technique below.

It looks like you're attempting to capture an image while leaving the canvas *untainted*. If this is the case, you can follow [this approach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image):

1. Configure your webserver to allow CORS on image files.
2. Capture an image off of the canvas without tainting it:

   ```js
   var img = new Image,
       canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
       ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
       src = "http://example.com/image"; // insert image url here

   img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

   img.onload = function() {
       canvas.width = img.width;
       canvas.height = img.height;
       ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
       localStorage.setItem("savedImageData", canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
   }
   img.src = src;
   // make sure the load event fires for cached images too
   if (img.complete || img.complete === undefined) {
       img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";
       img.src = src;
   }
   ```